# 4D and GLSL, are there any support for matrix 5x5?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I want to transform and project on screen 4D graphics with GLSL vertex shader. Does it have matrix 5x5 and 5D vectors support or extensions for it? And if not, how to properly send 5x5 matrices and etc to shader?

Comment: Do you have a use case for 5x5 matrices and vectors? Others have pointed out that there are solutions for working around this limitation, but GPU hardware is generally designed around 4-component data types. 3D vectors are in many respects 4D vectors with an unusable 4th component; thus if you decide to make a 5D vector, you will wind up with a 4D vector + 1 float + 3 unusable floats on some hardware ~= 2 4D vectors. Even on newer hardware that is scalar friendly, vertex attributes are always 4D. A 5D vertex attribute will require two slots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, glsl only has 2-, 3-, and 4-vectors and equivalent matrices (https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Data_Type_%28GLSL%29#Matrices). If you want 5x5 matrices sent to the shader you can do this by defining structs of floats or doubles yourself and passing them as uniforms, or if you need a lot, share them as a buffer of floats and read them in groups of 25. Keep in mind though that you'll also need to implement any math functions you need for these types yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a 5x5 matrix by passing a 4x4 and a 3x3 matrix and implementing matrix math in the vertex shader itself.